# How to remove account button and replace with simple account|login links?

Tags: login

I'm working on my e-commerce website and I have some trouble with the Header.

Can someone tell me please How to remove account button and replace with simple account|login links?

Comment: What's your Magento version?

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is my magento version 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to apply custom template only for Top Links, you can do it like this in your theme's local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">

        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/template/my_links.phtml</template>
        </action>

    </reference>
<default>
```

Then copy *page/template/links.phtml* and rename it to **page/template/my_links.phtml** and do whatever you need inside that new template file. For example you can add log-in & logout link add the below code:

```
 <?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo 'Log OUT'; ?></a>

    <?php 

else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">SIGN IN</a>
    <?php 

endif; ?>
```

To add a custom link to Top Links via local.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```